# Redux Saga - Take Every is never Called

Tags: redux, yield, redux-saga

I have this simple saga:

`export function* priceComparisonSaga() {
    yield takeEvery(RECORD_PRICE, priceComparison);
}`

But whenever I dispatch the event, it is never called. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the action in question had an extra "type" property.

When using the shortcut to create actions like this,

`export const addBalance = makeActionCreator(ADD_BALANCE,"balance","type");`

This action won't work, because the second type property overwrites "ADD_BALANCE". Instead, this works:

`export const addBalance = makeActionCreator(ADD_BALANCE,"balance","balancetype");`

Comment: This is a good reason to use the Flux Standard Action convention of putting all additional data inside of a `payload` field.